# How do show the result to user after he or she clicks multiple inline buttons

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So this is my code. Basically you guys are familiar with subway...i want to create a part whereby when the user clicks multiple buttons and then clicks ok, it returns whatever that user has clicked except the Ok.

```py
def sauce(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        if update.message.text == "Y" or update.message.text == "y":
            keyboard = ([
                    InlineKeyboardButton("No Sauce",callback_data='No Sauce'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Chipotle Southwest", callback_data='Chipotle Southwest'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Ranch", callback_data='Ranch'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("BBQ", callback_data='BBQ'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Chilli Sauce", callback_data='Chilli Sauce'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Tomato Sauce", callback_data='Tomato Sauce'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Mustard", callback_data='Mustard'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Mayonese", callback_data='Mayonese'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Sweet Onion", callback_data='Sweet Onion'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Hot Pepper", callback_data='Hot Pepper'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Cheese Sauce", callback_data='Cheese Sauce'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Sweet Chilli", callback_data='Sweet Chilli'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Garlic Aioli", callback_data='Garlic Aioli'),
                    InlineKeyboardButton("Honey Mustard", callback_data='Honey Mustard'),
                ])
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[button] for button in keyboard])

            update.message.reply_text('Please choose your sauces:', reply_markup = reply_markup)
            return CHECK2

        elif update.message.text == "N" or update.message.text == "n":
            update.message.reply_text("Please re-pick your option")
            return vegetables(update,context)

def check2(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        global sauces
        query = update.callback_query
        query.answer()
        sauces += query.data + ","
        query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {sauces}. Anymore(MAX 2)? Y/N")
        return SEASONING
```

I am only receiving back whatever that the user clicks once. E.g. if he clicks "no vegetables", he gets back "no vegetables", but if I click multiple buttons nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary whose key is the UserID and in the first step has an empty list

When the user clicks on any of these buttons, data with the desired and appropriate text will be entered into your list.

And finally, you can have the values ​​of the list After clicking on the OK button, you must set the list to an empty value

To determine the status of each key, you can also have the confirmation or disapproval of each key by checking the list

This way is an answer, if you have taken the idea I said you can easily implement it

Comment: sorry what do u mean my setting the list to an empty value

Comment: could u pls explain it a bit simpler..i am sorry

Comment: For example, you write => data_dict = { '12345 (that is UserID)' : [ (at first this is empty) ] , ...  }   and when the user clicks on any button u must add that item to the user list

Comment: and when the user clicks on OK, you can check all the things you have in the list, and even if the list is empty, you can notice that the user has not selected any option and the user just clicks the OK button and ...

Comment: I think this can be a way to solve your problem that can be achieved with a little thought and testing (:

Comment: So when the user starts entering any option i take his id store inside a dictionary as a key and then the value would be a list of his choices?

Answer (score 0):

You can store data per user/chat. Just define some variable with empty list and push new values from inline buttons there.

More [documentation about storing bot, user and chat related data](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot,-user-and-chat-related-data)

Comment: it doesnt work though because whenever i do that an error pops up that says query is too old  and bad query

Comment: @ShreyasHegde please provide a code sample of what you have tried.

Comment: query = update.callback_query
query.answer()
sauces += query.data + ","  query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {sauces}. Anymore(MAX 2)? Y/N")
return SEASONING

Comment: this is for sauces shld i do the same way for veggies? but the problem is i have to keep calling back the function rather than just calling it once and letting user click multiple times

Comment: @ShreyasHegde can you you add that code to original question? It is hard to read it in comments.

Comment: sure i will do that no worries

Comment: I have amended the previous code from vegetable to sauces